# Android how to check mobile number

Tags: android

In Android We can save mobile number/landline number/etc..how To check that the number is mobile number?

```
while (phones.moveToNext()) 
{                   
     int phoneType = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
     if (phoneType == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
     {
          phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));

          break;
     }
}
```

with this code it fetches the mobile number of **TYPE_MOBILE** ..but what if the user put land line number in **TYPE_MOBILE**?

Comment: You can use `RegEx` to verify the given/collected number is a valid mobile number. `^[789]\d{9}$` - This regex verifies the give number starts with `7 or 8 or 9` and has 10 numbers which i used to verify `Indian` mobile numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best way given inbuilt.

```
private boolean isValidMobile(String phone) 
    {
        return android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phone).matches();   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In android you will not get mobile number, if user save our own number in contact as owner then you will get. If you want user mobile number then you can use OTP verification related libraries and then you will got number

Comment: libphonenumber api will help to achieve that?

Comment: if use added any api for OTP then you will got phone number, but android not provide any function to get mobile number